# Help making my root directory not executable for CGI scripts

Tags: apache, cgi

I'm trying to make the root directory for a virtual host so that it can execute CGI scripts.
I put the following in my virtual host declaration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
    Options +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /path/to/root
    ServerName servername
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try execute the CGI script, it just downloads it instead.

Comment: This type of questions typically gets better responses on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use:

```
<Directory /path/to/root>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Location />
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

See [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) and [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) in Apache docs.